# File upload.php not working

Tags: php

I have following code.
**index.php**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <title>File Sharing</title>
    <body>
    <h1>File Sharing</h1><br/><br/>
    <form action="upload.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select File to Share:
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" >Share</button>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <p><a href="download.php"> or view shared files </a></p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and upload.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 50000000000000000000000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been shared.<br/>";
        echo "<br/><p><a href='index.php'>Go Back</a>or<a href='download.php'>View Shared files</a></p>";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
 }
 else{
     echo"error uploading";
 }
?>
```

following the above my files do not get uploaded. and gives "**error uploading"** i got many questions for this problem i tried all but none solves my problem. What's the error???

Comment: Too funny but true that 50YB files are too big to been stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong method for your form. You can't "GET" data to your server. You must "POST" it.

http://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/664241-using-html-forms-pass-data-php

Scott

Answer (score 1):

My friend you should replace your GET method with POST 
otherwise code working fine

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select File to Share:
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" >Share</button>
    </form>
```